# How to add variables to request()->all()? (Laravel 6.0)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-helper

I have Laravel 6.0 with something like this using the `request()->all();` helper to create a new row on the database...

```
$input = request()->all();
Service::create($input);
```

I want to add two variables to it manually so that we don't need the user to add them manually. I have tried variations on this...

```
$time = time();
$input = array_merge(request()->all(), ['serviceSite' => 'companyname', 'serviceOrderedTime' => $time]);
Service::create($input);
```

Is there a way to do this with the `request()` helper or do I have to use an alternative method?

Comment: You could make those columns have default values in DB already, not needing you to add them manually here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
$time = time();
$input = $request->all();
$input['serviceSite'] = 'companyname';
$input['serviceOrderedTime'] = $time;
Service::create($input);
```

Make sure `serviceSite` and `serviceOrderedTime` fillable in your model.

IF you want to merge it with `$request` then you can do like this.

```
$request->merge(["key"=>"value"]);
```

### As your Way.

```
  $time = time(); 
  $request->request->add(['serviceSite' => 'companyname','serviceOrderedTime'=>$time]);
  Service::create($request->all());
```

Comment: Thx,, include in model is very important

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper function in laravel `collection` called `add`
you can use it like this

```
$request->add(['serviceSite' => 'companyname']);
$request->add(['serviceOrderedTime' => $time]);
Service::create($request->all());
```

or you can make it by the common way

```
$request = request()->all();
$request['serviceSite'] = 'companyName';
$request['serviceOrderedTime'] = $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can set a variable to your request:

```php
$request->request->set('serviceSite', 'serviceSite');
$request->request->set('serviceOrderedTime', $time);
```

In order to allow [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment), the `serviceSite` and `serviceOrderedTime` may be include in your `$fillable` model property.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a new key value in FormRequest file, you can do it

```
class CreateKubernetesRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'zone' => 'required|exists:zone_offerings,name',
        ];
        $this->request->add(['version_id' => "SOME ID"]);

        return $rules;
        
    } 

}
```